# How to access files in other packages without using a dummy class

Tags: java, getresource

I am actually loading OWL files in my java web app with the following code:

```
InputStream is = Dummy.class.getResourceAsStream("content.owl");
```

I created `Dummy.class` in the same package as `content.owl` is to get access to this file.

Is there a (refactor-safe) way to load `content.owl` directly without the need of a dummy class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get that resource from any class by giving relative path of it according to location of output folder where your compiled files are put.

For example initially the resource file in **proj/src/a/b/content.owl** package and the class I access this resource is in package **proj/src/a/b/c/d/MyClass.java**. After building the project my executables go under bin folder and the class I access the resource goes to **proj/bin/a/b/c/d/MyClass.class** directory and resource goes into **proj/bin/a/b/content.owl**.

And as **bin** folder is specified as the output folder in classpath of my project, I can access to resource with the code:

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/a/b/content.owl");
```

Comment: That sounds nice. But ist this refactor safe? What if the name of content.owl changes? How do i prevent a runtime error?

Comment: Well, I think if the error rising from not being able to load this resource is tolerable the input stream may be checked if it is null, if not tolerable, you can try giving the path of the resource as an additional parameter or configuration or there may be any other workaround if such a name change is possible. I think you should know the new name of the resource eventually.